# Error importing old MDF database to SQL Server 2019 on a new machine

Tags: sql-server

On my old machine, I have SQL Server 2008. I have a database placed in a specific folder.

I am now moving to a new machine and I have duplicated the setup with file placements.

On the new machine I have downloaded SQL Server 2019 Express and SQL Server Management Studio 18.

OK. So doing this simply I make sure SQL Server Express is running, open SSMS and in Object Explorer I choose "Mynewmachine\SQLExpress" - "Databases" and I click "Attach" pick my database (MDF file on local disk)

However doing this I get error:

> Attached Database failed for server Mynewmachine\SQLExpress
> (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo) Additional information: An exception
> occurred while executing a transact-sql statement or batch
> (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo) A network-related or
> instance-specific error occurred while establishing connection to SQL
> Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that
> the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
> allow remote connections. (Provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26
>
> - Error location Server/Instance Specified) /Microsoft SQL Server)

This makes little sense. Server is running on local machine. Database files are on local machine (in fact specific database + SQL Server have always been only used locally on old/new machine). Thus there is nothing here with remote connections or anything like that.

I am wondering if this this in an instance name issues. On my new server it is called `SQLEXPRESS`, and on my old it was `MSSQLServer`. Should I install a new instance if MSSQLSERVER using the same instance name as on my old machine? Would I then be able to import more easily?

Comment: It has nothing to do with your instance names - the only reason is the **version** - SQL Server 2019 just simply doesn't support restoring / attaching SQL Server 2008 database files directly. You will need to use an intermediate step - e.g. reattaching your SQL Server 2008 database to a 2014 instance, updating the compatibility level, backup from there, and **then** restore to 2019. See [Supported versions and editions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/supported-version-and-edition-upgrades-2019?view=sql-server-ver15) as to what SQL Server 2019 supports

Comment: Not sure if the backup/restore path would work - instead of detaching from SQL Server 2008 - try to **backup** to a `.bak` file, and then try to restore that in SQL Server 2019.

Comment: @marc_s Thanks. The link you gave states "Backup and restore: A backup taken on SQL Server 2008 or SQL Server 2008 R2 can be restored to SQL Server 2019." So maybe it is possible. A bit annoying though but will try

Comment: You mention an mdf file. What about the transaction log file, though?

Comment: I think log is lost which... is of course kinda bad but... well... it appears to work using backup/restore for the data itself. I think that is okay in my situation. Still working out why my ADO code can no  longer connect to MSSQL2019 but that is probably for a separate stackoverflow. I will return back and accept an answer pointing to backup/restore...